# To find field extension of $Z_3$ for given p(x).

Tags: field-theory

Find an extension field E of $Z_3$ in which P(x)=$x^2+1$ has a root. Also find the cardinality of E.

The question here seems to be east but I need to verify my answer. 
Here roots of P(x) are i & -i. So the field extension is $Z_3[i]$ and cardinality is 4.
If I am wrong then please guide me.

Comment: Perhaps you meant $\Bbb{Z}_{3} \cup i$ or $\Bbb{Z}_{3}[i]$ in the last line?

Comment: I edited. You can now reread the answer

Comment: You say the cardinality of $\Bbb Z_3[i]$ is $4$, that means there should be only four elements. Three of them are $0, 1, 2$ from $\Bbb Z_3$ itself, and two others are $i$ and $-i$, and suddenly there are five elements (at least!). I think you should count again.

Comment: Seems correct to me.Yes, you could have included either $i$ or $-i$ as the question asks for "a"  root.Is asking for a single root in an extension field of a 2nd degree polynomial wrong? @Arthur

Comment: If you make an extension (_any_ extension) which contains one root of $x^2+1$, then that extension will automatically contain the other root as well. This is true for any extension of any field by adjoing the roots of a second degree polynomial, by polynomial division.

Comment: $-1$ is congruent to $2$ mod $3$!

Comment: @KavitaSahu No, that's mod $2$, and it is the source of much strangeness (you often see "field of characteristic different from $2$" in theorems). In $\Bbb Z_3$, $-1$ is congruent to $2$, and that is much nicer.

Comment: Yes you are right so E has 4 elements

Comment: as said by Arthur,if $i$ is in the extension field,then $-i$ is also in the extension field,so the extension field has atleast $5$ elements!

Comment: Then according to Arthur there are 4 elements not 5 as $Z_3$ consists 3 elements and we attach only i to it

Comment: @KavitaSahu No, that's not what I said. If we include $i$ but not $-i$, then the result wouldn't be a _ring_ because the additive structure wouldn't be a _group_. There is a minimum of elements that need to be added for the result to be a ring, and that minimum number is at _least_ $2$ since if you include $i$ you must clearly include $-i$. Thus we go from a cardinality of $3$ to _at least_ $5$, which was what my first comment was about.

Answer (score 0):

$Z_3[i]$= { a+bi / a,b $\in$ $Z_3$}

```
                       = { 0,i,2i,1,1+ i,1+ 2i,2,2+ i,2,+2i}
```

So |E|= 9

Answer (score 0):

You need to say what $i$ stands for. It certainly cannot be the imaginary unit of $\mathbb C$.

The correct answer is probably the quotient ring $E=\mathbb{Z}_3 [X] /(X^2+1)$.

By polynomial division, every element in $E$ is represented in a unique way by $a+bX$ and so $E$ has $9$ elements.

So, by taking $j = X \bmod (X^2+1)$,we have $E= \mathbb{Z}_3 [j] = \{ a+bj: a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ with $j^2=-1$.